# Why is jQuery performing an Ajax GET when I ask it to POST

Tags: jquery, http, http-post, http-get

Given this very simple HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: "/MyURL/",
                data: "TEST",
                type: "POST"
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I load this page with Fiddler observing.

**The HTTP request is observed to be a GET rather than the requested POST. Why?**

Comment: I think you write your $.Ajax wrong

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hLBF/1/

Comment: #Rory Becker
I tried the above code but it is not correct
look at answer that I posted I tried, it was right

Comment: @Kermani Your change appears to be sending JSON rather than a literal string. In both cases the result is a GET rather than the requested POST.

Comment: @Rory Becker, there is a way for testing: use other libraries or write your own Ajax code with **xmlhttprequest** and see the Fiddler again. I think the problem is not from Jquery

Comment: @Kermani I'm unsure of your reasoning as to "the problem is not from Jquery". Especially when a change from jQuery 1.10.2 -> 1.11.0 seems to eliminate the problem with no other code changes.

Comment: @Kermani FWIW I agree it seems unlikely, but it's hard to argue with the evidence.

Comment: @Rory Becker Okay, I'm not a jquery rights organizations :) , and surely you are right. if you say that it may have used jquery site that will lower security
See this page that is not using jquery and say what Fiddler says http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post

Comment: FWIW: That POSTs correctly as expected

Comment: Unable to reproduce... Tell your browser and it's version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your local copy of jQuery 1.10.2 is modified in some way, maybe overwritting global ajax option to make all ajax requests using GET method. You should then update your jq local copy or use any CDN. ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: This was an illusion caused by a local custom version of jQuery 1.10.2

---

It seems that jQuery 1.10.2 suffers from this problem, but it is "Fixed" (assuming that it's a bug in the first place) in jQuery 1.11.0.

With luck this will prevent someone else from tearing their hair out :)

Comment: Any reference regarding this bug? Anyway, thx for sharing it!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it

Comment: I'm going to hold off accepting my own answer until I can get confirmation from someone else. :)

Comment: @A.Wolff are you saying that you do not observe a GET in Fiddler? or are you saying the data appears to get through to your backend system? Many frameworks appear to be able to cope with data coming in via GET when expected as POST. In my real world case however, I require a POST, since our payload data exceeds the URL limit.

Comment: When doing a POST request using jq 1.10.2, i see the POST request getting send and get result as expected. I don't see any bug here. But i'm not using Fiddler to check but the network tab in dev tools. But is it only on jquery 1.10.2, not e.g on 1.10.1 that you get this behaviour?

Comment: Quickly checking jquery source, i don't see any difference between ajax implementation regarding jq 1.10.2 and jq 1.11.0  EDIT: there are 4 renaming variables, that's all i can see and anyway not relevant to your issue

Comment: References to that "Fixed" please.

Comment: @A.Wolff Have just tried using both FF and IE Network tabs and have confirmed GET rather than POST, but only on jQuery 10.2

Comment: @A.Wolff I have also tried to replicate this problem with 1.10.1 and found that said version is fine.

Comment: @A.Wolff ie 1.10.1 - good, 1.10.2 - bad, 1.11.1 - good again :(

Comment: @Serhiy Sorry. I didn't mean to imply that I have any knowledge of this being a known bug. I'm simply stating that it appears broken in 1.10.2, but as discussed, appears fine in 1.10.1 and 1.11.0

Comment: @A.Wolff You are 'The man' (or woman... I make no judgements). I don't know how. I don't know why. but it appears our local copy of 1.10.2 is very much non-standard. Acquiring a CDN copy has fixed this issue. Please post this suggestion as an Answer so I can mark it as correct and draw attention away from my incorrect answer. I may even delete said answer.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var variable="TEST";
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                data: ({test:variable}),
                type: "post"
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I run your code copied exactly, and Fiddler says that it produces a GET and not a POST. :(

Comment: dear @Rory Becker, I just do not know what the Fiddler is, but I think it is important that the **server-side languages**, will get the **post** variables or **Get** variable. for example when you test this with php you will have a variable like this **$_POST['test']**

Comment: There are many differences between GETs and POSTs. Critical in my real world case is that all data sent as GET is placed in the URL which has a much stricter limit on the quantity of data that may be passed. POST is able to carry many times more data than GET. This is why we require POST. AFIACT this is an entirely client side issue.